# Google Sheets Apps Script to insert timestamp when specific users edits specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a gsheet used for tracking. Currently, the script inserts a timestamp when any cell is edited/added (by any user) in columns A-Z. I am looking for help to revise the code so that a timestamp is inserted in column AA if I edit cells in columns F-R and another timestamp in column AB cells, only when my colleague edits the cells in columns Y-Z.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var rr = e.range;
    var ss = e.range.getSheet();

    var headerRows = 1;  // # header rows to ignore

    if (rr.getRow() <= headerRows) return;

    const sh = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sh.getName() == "2022 Agreement Tracker") {
    var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yy - h:mm a - ");
    var usern = e.user.getUsername();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,27).setValue(dt + usern);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps in multiple ranges

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const hr = 1;
  if (sh.getName() == "2022 Agreement Tracker" && e.range.rowStart > hr) {
    const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yy - h:mm a - ");
    const user = e.user.getUsername()
    if (e.range.columnStart > 5 && e.range.columnStart < 19) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 26).setValue(dt + user);
    }
    if (e.range.columnStart > 24 && e.range.columnStart < 27) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 28).setValue(dt + user);
    }
  }
}
```